# MATCH comma separated list of numbers to a column in Excel (no macros, no TEXTJOIN)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to match a cell with comma separated numbers (M) against a column of numbers (B), such that if any of the comma separated numbers do NOT appear in the column, the result is false.

I have already this solution:

```
{=COUNT(MATCH(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(M2,",",REPT(" ",100)),(Num_Array-1)*100+1,100)),$B$2:$B$7,0))=(LEN(M2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(M2,",",""))+1)}
```

at this link:

https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/654920-match-comma-delimited-values-cell-against-individual-values-column.html

which works perfectly if all the values are text.  But if all the values are numbers, it always returns false.

Test data I used is:
[test data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F49D9.png)

Comment: this solution fails on M5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to iterate the values in each cell and test:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(ISNUMBER(MATCH(--TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(M2,",",REPT(" ",999)),(ROW($XFD$1:INDEX($XFD:$XFD,LEN(M2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(M2,",",""))+1))-1)*999+1,999)),$B:$B,0))))=LEN(M2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(M2,",",""))+1
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

---

Using your COUNT array formula:

```
=COUNT(MATCH(--TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(M2,",",REPT(" ",999)),(ROW($XFD$1:INDEX($XFD:$XFD,LEN(M2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(M2,",",""))+1))-1)*999+1,999)),$B:$B,0))=LEN(M2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(M2,",",""))+1
```

Needs confirmation with Ctrl-Shift-Enter to work.

I prefer the SUMPRODUCT because it does not need the Ctrl-Shift-Enter confirmation.

Comment: Nice once again!

Comment: Thanks, this does the trick!  I, too, prefer not to use array formulas.  Looking at yours in detail, it seems as though the only substantive difference is in the ROW calculation.  I confess I don't quite get what's going on there...

Comment: That is the part that does the iteration.  With the process you have it requires a named range that returns 1-255.  Mine only returns the number of items in the cell, less iterations and self contained. @MattCrandall